# Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy. Socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, cors

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const { createServer } = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");

const PORT = 5000;

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://chit-chat-frontend-red.vercel.app",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["content-type"],
  },
  // allowRequest: function (req, callback) {
  //   callback(
  //     null,
  //     req.headers.referer.startsWith(
  //       "https://chit-chat-frontend-red.vercel.app"
  //     )
  //   );
  // },
});

// io.origins(["http://localhost:5000"]);
// io.origins(["https://chit-chat-frontend-red.vercel.app"]);
```

I have included cors but still getting the same error.I have tried various methods but still same error while deploying.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXagl.png)